# If and search condition in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have 7 LinkedHashMap that contains some String values. I want to search that how many LinkedHashMap contains the key and how many LinkedHashMaps don’t contain the searched value. Below is my sample Java code. In sample Java code, I only used five LinkedHashMaps. It tells which LinkedHashMap contains the search term only.

```
public void sampleFunction(
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> h1,
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> h2, 
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> h3,
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> h4,
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> h5) {

    String searchMe = "something";

    if(h1.containsValue(searchMe)){
        System.out.println("I am in h1");
    }
    if(h2.containsValue(searchMe)){
        System.out.println("I am in h2");
    }
    if(h3.containsValue(searchMe)){
        System.out.println("I am in h3");
    }
    if(h4.containsValue(searchMe)){
        System.out.println("I am in h4");
    }
    if(h5.containsValue(searchMe)){
        System.out.println("I am in h5");
    }

}
```

### EDIT

For example:
Let's say I pass 7 LinkedHashMaps to a function. The function should be able to tell me which of the passed LinkedHashMaps contain the searched term. Output of the function could be:

H1 h2 and h3 LinkedHashMaps contains the key and h4, h5, h6, h7 missed the searched term.

Based on each combination of output I would call appropriate function in my program. For example, if h2 and h3 contains the value then I may call fBill or fPay.

Comment: This question is unclear or not even a question. You should be clear about what you are asking to make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried to put an example to explain my question.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing that makes it confusing is the fact that you are not really asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

Use varargs:

```
public void sampleFunction(LinkedHashMap<String, String>... hs) {
    String searchMe = "something";
    for(LinkedHashMap<String, String> h : hs) {
        if(h.containsValue(searchMe)) {
            //do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also write functions like these to accept a collection of arguments, so in this case: `Collection<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please take a look at the edited question. Your answer tells which LinkedHashMaps contain the key. However, it does not give me the combinations of LinkedHashMaps that contain the searched term.